# How to fix to force text to split in table?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I have a simple table in LibreOffice calc and I tried to convert it to latex using the Calc2Latex macro.

Then using Latex I tried to improve it. However I cannot get the text correctly !

This is what I want the text to be like in the table:
[image]

For example, in the first column, "Message per minute per source" is divided.

However, in my latex generated table, that does not happen! It is all a big mess:
[image]

I tried fixing the problem using `tabularx` and I read somewhere that I should not use `multicolumn`, but I am still a newbie and I do not know how to fix this!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

%define some nice colors
\definecolor{middleware_green}{RGB}{82, 119, 17}
\definecolor{middleware_white}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\definecolor{middleware_light_gray}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
\definecolor{middleware_dark_gray}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{F}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries}p{2.5cm}}%
\newcolumntype{R}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedright\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedleft\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}{|>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\centering\arraybackslash\sffamily}X|}%
\rowcolors{2}{middleware_white}{middleware_light_gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R|L|L|L|}
\hline\rowcolor{middleware_green}
\multicolumn{ 4}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{1 Source, 1 Session, 1 Client, Exp0}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Messages per minute per source}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Middleware Exec Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Delay (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Average Delay (s)}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{60} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{0.00} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{120} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{0.00} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{240} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{0.00} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 60 & 0 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{480} & 69 & 9 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{16.67} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 69 & 9 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 92 & 32 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{1000} & 159 & 99 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{109.67} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 173 & 113 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 177 & 117 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{2000} & 391 & 331 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{311.00} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 383 & 323 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 339 & 279 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 1}{|r|}{4000} & 561 & 501 & \multicolumn{ 1}{r|}{512.33} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 631 & 501 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
\multicolumn{ 1}{|l|}{} & 595 & 535 & \multicolumn{ 1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\label{}
\caption{}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The main reason i want to make the columns smaller is so they can take less space and so hopefully I can put some text next to them or put 2 tables one next to another !

Comment: Yes, try removing all the `\multicolumn` stuff. E.g, if you have `\multicolumn{1}{l}{X}`, replace this with `X`. If you have `\multicolumn{1}{c}{<Stuff>}` in a cell, then that will override the column you specified after `\begin{tabular}`, so it doesn't matter if you have an `X` column, as using `\multicolumn` like that disallows the line breaking in that cell. (Don't do it for the first row, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `X` column allows it's contents to break, but when you do `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Lots of text}` you override that column specifier. That will cell will behave as a `c` column, which does not allow for line breaking.

To have a the column heading centered, while still allowing for line breaks, and have the rest of the column right aligned, use a `\multicolumn` with your `C` column, e.g. `\multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Messages per minute per source}}`.

The rest of the `\multicolumn{1}{..` stuff I think you can remove. In the complete code below, there is one table with vertical rules, one without. I think you can use the one without, but I'll leave it for you to decide.

These tables are set at `0.45\textwidth`, so they could be a little bit wider and there would still be room for two next to each other. If you don't need that, they can of course be much wider.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

%define some nice colors
\definecolor{middleware_green}{RGB}{82, 119, 17}
\definecolor{middleware_white}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\definecolor{middleware_light_gray}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
\definecolor{middleware_dark_gray}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries}p{2.5cm}}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedright\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\raggedleft\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\leavevmode\ignorespaces\centering\arraybackslash\sffamily}X}%
\rowcolors{2}{middleware_white}{middleware_light_gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.45\textwidth}{LLLL}
\hline\rowcolor{middleware_green}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{1 Source, 1 Session, 1 Client, Exp0}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Messages per minute per source}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Middle\-ware Exec Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Delay (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C}{\textbf{Average Delay (s)}} \\ \hline
60 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
120 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
240 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
480 & 69 & 9 & 16.67 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 69 & 9 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 92 & 32 &  \\ \hline
1000 & 159 & 99 & 109.67 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 173 & 113 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 177 & 117 &  \\ \hline
2000 & 391 & 331 & 311.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 383 & 323 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 339 & 279 &  \\ \hline
4000 & 561 & 501 & 512.33 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 631 & 501 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 595 & 535 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{.45\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|}
\hline\rowcolor{middleware_green}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{1 Source, 1 Session, 1 Client, Exp0}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|C|}{\textbf{Messages per minute per source}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{\textbf{Middle\-ware Exec Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{\textbf{Delay (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{C|}{\textbf{Average Delay (s)}} \\ \hline
60 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
120 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
240 & 60 & 0 & 0.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 60 & 0 &  \\ \hline
480 & 69 & 9 & 16.67 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 69 & 9 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 92 & 32 &  \\ \hline
1000 & 159 & 99 & 109.67 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 173 & 113 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 177 & 117 &  \\ \hline
2000 & 391 & 331 & 311.00 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 383 & 323 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 339 & 279 &  \\ \hline
4000 & 561 & 501 & 512.33 \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 631 & 501 &  \\ \cline{ 2- 3}
 & 595 & 535 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Look, two tables!}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I have (yet) another problem (I cannot make my tables show one next to another) but I will create a new question for that!

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution, based on `makecell` though it's far from perfect. However, I think it's interesting because the code is much more compact.

It has problems with colours: the first two rows are fine, but the following rows are not entirely coloured,  for reasons that I don't understand since the code is not fundamentally different from the code for the second row (I tested replacing the `\multirow` commands in the 4th row with `\makecell`, without any change in the resulting table).

So if anyone could explain what is the problem…

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage[margin=2.54cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}%booktabs,
    \usepackage{array}

    %define some nice colors
    \usepackage[font = sf]{caption}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\cellalign}{rc}

    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{middleware_green}{RGB}{82, 119, 17}
    \definecolor{middleware_white}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
    \definecolor{middleware_light_gray}{RGB}{239, 239, 239}
    \definecolor{middleware_dark_gray}{RGB}{153, 153, 153}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \rowcolors{2}{White}{Olive!15!}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \sffamily\centering
    \label{}
    \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|}%
    \hline\rowcolor{middleware_green}
    \multicolumn{ 4}{|c|}{\Gape[8pt]{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{1 Source, 1 Session, 1 Client, Exp0}}}} \\ %
    \hline%
    \makecell*{Messages\\ per minute\\ per source} & \makecell{Middleware Exec\\ Time (s)} & \makecell{Delay (s)}& \makecell{Average\\ Delay (s)} \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{360} & \makecell{60\\ 60\\60} & \makecell{0\\0\\0} & \multirowcell{3}{0.00} \\
     \hline\rowcolor{Olive!20!}%%
     \multirowcell{3}{120} & \makecell*{60\\60\\60} & \makecell{0\\0\\0} & \multirowcell{3}{0.00} \\%
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{240} & \makecell*{60\\60\\60} & \makecell{0\\0\\0} & \multirowcell{3}{0.00} \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{480} & \makecell*{69\\69\\92} & \makecell{9\\9\\32}& \multirowcell{3}{16.67} \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{1000} & \makecell*{159\\173\\177} & \makecell{99\\113\\117} & \multirowcell{3}{109.67} \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{2000} & \makecell*{391\\383\\339} & \makecell{331\\323\\279} & \multirowcell{3}{311.00} \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{4000} & \makecell*{561\\631\\595} & \makecell{501\\501\\535} & \multirowcell{3}{512.33} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Already fixed it, but thx for trying!